# Suppress output of Enumerable::each in irb

Tags: ruby, irb

The return value of Enumerable::each is the object that called each.

When I am inside irb this is really annoying since I get huge outputs.
Is it possible to suppress the return value of Enumerable::each in irb?

For example this

```
[1,2].each {|u| puts "hey"}
```

output this

```
>> [1,2].each {|u| puts "hey"}
hey
hey
=> [1, 2]
```

I want to get rid of the last line

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That is simple.

Just add a semicolon(`;`) at end of the statement/expression in Ruby whose return value you don't want to see and also add `nil`.

Make it:

```
[1,2].each {|u| puts "hey"}; nil
```

But please note that there is no reason to suppress the `irb` output(*except when the return value is too large/lot of text*); it helps a lot in debugging and to know what exactly is going on in the function.

Comment: This makes IRB wait for another line, appending `;nil` works for me.

Comment: Thanks. You are right. I tried that out before posting in `pry`, which perfectly works with just `;`. Just tried in `irb` and `nil` was needed

Comment: For the sake of speed, `[1,2].each {|u| puts "hey"};0` is also fine. Or even `![1,2].each {|u| puts "hey"}`.

Comment: I think `nil` will still be faster. It's `ancestors` tree is far more shorter than a Fixnum like 0.

Comment: @kiddorails Faster to type.

Comment: thank you. I wanted to suppress it because I have a huge output

Answer (score 1):

Add the `--noecho` flag.

How it works:

```
$ irb --noecho
```